# how to set route without di/instance/alias in zf2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Problem that I can not solve is a route in zend framework 2.

I use [zend skeleton application](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication). I created controller and appropriate view files like in zf1. And if I try open created controlled from browser application returns 404 return code until I add alias:

```
<?php
return array(
    'di' => array(
        'instance' => array(
            'alias' => array (
                'login' => 'Application\Controller\LoginController',
                'logout' => 'Application\Controller\LogoutController',
                'user' => 'Application\Controller\UserController',
            ),
```

And I should add all controllers files in alias array.

How to make default route without adding aliases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instance alias are not intended for use in routes, but are "shortcuts" useful for the DI.
For example, suppose you're inside a method invoked on a module event:

```
// get the di locator
$di = $e->getTarget()->getLocator();
// get instance by alias
$loginController = $di->get('login');
```

Instead, to setup routes rules you can do this in your config file:

```
// Setup for router and routes
return array(
    'di' => array(
        'instance' => array(

        ....

            // Setup for router and routes
        'Zend\Mvc\Router\RouteStack' => array(
            'parameters' => array(
                'routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController',
                                'action'     => 'index',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                    'home' => array(
                        'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '/',
                            'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController',
                                'action'     => 'index',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

I suggest you the [Akrabat's Getting started tutorial](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2-tutorial/)

Comment: I have this (Zend\Mvc\Router\RouteStack) section in my config file, but does not seem that it works. Might be should I re-clone skeleton application?

Comment: Have you configured your application module in application.config.php? Have a look also here [link](http://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/zend.mvc.quick-start.html)